# Type casting gcc error with const modifier

Tags: c, gcc, opengl, g++

I'm playing around with OpenGL and decided to implement a function that would load shader source code from file to string.

OpenGL is expecting to get `const char*`.

So here is the function I got:

```c
const char* string_from_file(const char* filename) {
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error while trying to open %s file\n", filename);
       exit(1);
    }
    char* buf = (char*) malloc(MAX_SHADER_FILE_SIZE);
    char c;
    size_t i = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        buf[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return buf; 
}
```

Error I'm getting from gcc:

[image: screenshot of text]

```c
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SHADER_FILE_SIZE 200

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
void _print_shader_info_log(GLuint shader_index); 

const char* string_from_file(const char *filename);

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

const char *vertexShaderSource = string_from_file("src/shaders/main_vert.glsl");
const char *fragmentShaderSource = string_from_file("src/shaders/main_frag.glsl");
```

If compiled with g++ there is no error, it builds and runs.

So error says: `initializer element is not compile-time constant`. Why does it have to be compile-time constant? Isn't `const type*` supposed to mean: the thing that this is pointed to should not be altered? Why is this error not there if compiled with g++?

Comment: You're trying to call a function, `string_from_file()` in an initialiser, outside of any function. You can't do that.

Comment: All code, input, and output should be posted directly in the question *as text*, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: Aside: `char c` should be `int c`.

Comment: ≠ is windows terminal thing, I guess.

Comment: Some more points about that function: you didn't close the file, and the caller won't know how many active elements there are in `buf`, and you have not protected against buffer overflow. And if the data is binary, open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Fair point about closing file and buffer overflow. But what is active element? And it is code file > text > not binary, isn't it?

Comment: You mean I nead EOF at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the character array pointed to by your pointer variable being `const`. It's because you're trying to call a function from the global scope, outside of any function, which you absolutely can't do in C. It will probably work better if you do it like:

```c
const char *vertexShaderSource;
...
int main(void)
{
    vertexShaderSource = string_from_file("src/shaders/main_vert.glsl");
...
}
```

Comment: Whoops, C# background here.

Comment: Re "*This has nothing to do with your variable being const.*", It would be relevant if the variable was `const`, but it's not. (`*vertexShaderSource` is `const`, but not `vertexShaderSource` itself.)